# Создание таблицы many to many

Tags: mysql

Нужно создать таблицу персонажа (character). Он имеет множество параметров(attribute, build, skill, quirk, advantage, disadvantege). Среди них есть и те которые хранятся не в единственном экземпляре (skill, quirk, advantage, disadvantege). 
   Как правильно создать таблицу character_list? Можно ли создать 1 таблицу mant to many для хранения всех параметров или нужно сделать по таблице many-to-many к каждой таблице? Если данный вариант приемлемый, то что в данном случае будет primary key?
[image: Character table]

Comment: что символизирует таблица character_list, а что - character?

Comment: character  это таблица персонажа. character_list это связь many-to-many 
для таблицы character с таблицами skill, quirk, advantage, disadvantege.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как бы, так и делаете.

Таблица character:

character_id - собсно, id персонажа

atribute_id, build_id - два поля, ссылающиеся на id соответствующих записей в соответствующих таблицах.

character_list_id - id, ссылающийся на "список персонажа" - но лучше название поменять, потому что оно сбивает с толку (мне вначале подумалось, что это что-то типа "списка персонаж**ей**" - например на аккаунте пользователя).

И всё, в этой таблице больше ничего не нужно. Вообще. Остальные таблицы без изменений оставляете.

Совет: прежде чем фигачить таблицы сходу - сначала нарисуйте их, прямо на листочке, пропишите где что будет, прямо-таки нарисуйте эти самые "многие ко многи" - и все-все связи. И не от таблицы к таблице - а конкретно от поля к полю.